# Cannot use installed module on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x

I've written some code to collect API data and publish it to `MQTT`. This all works fine within PyCharm, but when I try running it on a Raspberry Pi, where it's going to live, it doesn't work.

I've installed all dependencies on the Raspberry Pi using `pip`, but when I run the script, I get an error.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
```

This is the error I get:

> File "main.py", line 1, in 
>      import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
>    ImportError: No module named paho.mqtt.client

Comment: use pip3 instead pip or better `python -m pip install`

Comment: I actually did (use pip3), pip3 list show the module as installed

Comment: How do you run your script: `python script.py` or `python3 script.py`?, use `python3 script.py`

Comment: I use `python script.py` from the directory where the files are stored, if I use `python3 script.py` I get a host of different errors

Comment: by default in rpi python points to python2 so you must install paho with pip2: `pip2 install foo` or `python -m pip install foo`

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was indeed a python version issue